# Ember camelCase attributes not loading

Tags: json, ember.js, camelcasing

My Ember router pings the server for a `photos` JSON file every 5 seconds (long polling). It loops over the JSON and adds (using EmberData's `push`) a photo to the store if the photo id does not yet exist. Using the workflow described by [Yoran Brondsema](http://yoranbrondsema.com/live-polling-system-ember-js/).

A snippet from the JSON file:

```
...
{
  "id": 45,
  "created_at": "2014-06-02T08:10:29.000Z"
}
...
```

Ember.js converts the `created_at` snake_case to the `createdAt` camelCased version and when I reload the page everything looks fine. The `{{createdAt}}` is available in the Handlebars template. But...

When the poller adds the photo model to the store the `createdAt` camelCased attribute is undefined. It works when I rename it the field in the JSON file to `createdAt` using camelCasing.

Should I not expect the camelCased attributes to be there when pushing to the store? Is the store outdated? Is it a timing issue where Ember didn't convert the attribute yet?

My store adapter looks like this:

```
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

It's a Rails backend (using ActiveModel::Serializer) but don't think that has anything to do with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the code from the [post](http://yoranbrondsema.com/live-polling-system-ember-js/) mentioned in the question does not use the Ember Data RESTAdapter so Ember does not convert the snake_cases from the JSON response.